# ArcGIS Field Calculator Not Working With Date Field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, sql, python-parser, datetime

I am trying to calculate a field based on the date values in another field. Here is my code from the pre-logic script code box:

```
def getHalf(dfield):
  if dfield >= date '2017-08-27 00:00:00' AND dfield < date '2017-08-27 
  12:00:00':
    return 1
```

The field calculator fails on line 2. The input field is formatted as a date field, its values look like this when viewed in the attribute table:

```
8/27/2017 10:05:00 PM
```

However they look like this when I perform a select by attributes on the field, so I am pretty sure I got the syntax right:

```
date '2017-08-27 22:05:00'
```

And then of course this is the line of code attempting to calculate the field:

```
getHalf(!timestamp_cst!)
```

Comment: Your syntax is not correct - you've mixed SQL with Python.  You need to use python's `datetime` to ensure you're treating them as dates

Comment: That's odd as when I use the following syntax in the select by attributes box, it works: timestamp_cst >= date '2017-08-28 00:00:00' AND timestamp_cst < date '2017-08-28 12:00:00'

Comment: Select by Attributes uses SQL, your field calculator is using Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mixed SQL syntax with Python syntax.  The Select by Attributes uses SQL but the  Field Calculator python parser uses python.

```
def getHalf(dfield):
    df = datetime.datetime.strptime(dfield, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
    d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-08-27 00:00:00', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
    d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-08-27 12:00:00', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
    if df >= d1 and df < d2:
        return 1
```

This may depend on how your dates are stored - mine are different to yours, so I've had to use the `strptime()` format differently to yours, and I have tried to adjust here based on the dates you've shown in your question.  For more info on the formatting tags see [Python - Basic date and time types - 8.1.7. strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Explanation:

```
df = datetime.datetime.strptime(dfield, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Tell python that your date field `timestamp_cst` contains a date.  Python now stores this as a datetime object `df`.

```
d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-08-27 00:00:00', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-08-27 12:00:00', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Put your start/end dates (times) into datetime objects for comparison against your date field.

```
if df >= d1 and df < d2:
    return 1
```

This runs the comparison of the datetime objects, so you are comparing datetime against datetime against datetime, not string against string or string against date etc.

Comment: Ah, I see now. This worked perfectly, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @blwoods If you are going to use this regularly I would recommend you rename the `d1` and `d2` to something more memorable so you know what they actually represent in your calculation.